# DIV not closing in foreach

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having this problem. I wrote this PHP to output the content of sub-folders in a specified folder. The code works great, it shows all the images in the sub-folders. The problem that I'm having is that on `echo $underfolder`, it prints out just the first sub-folder without closing the `DIV` `class=image`.

What's wrong? I'm going crazy

```html
 <div class="folders">
<?php
global $current_user;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();  
$current_user_nambre = $current_user->user_login;
$subFolders = glob("wp-content/uploads/$current_user_nambre/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);

     
    foreach ($subFolders as $value) {
        
                echo "<div class='products'>";
        $content = scandir($value);
        echo $value;
        foreach ($content as $value) {
            
            echo "<div class='image;' style=\"display:inline-block;\">";
            echo "<a href='/$underfolder/$value'>download</a>";
                    echo "<img src='/$underfolder/$value' height=\"100\height=\"100\" width=\"100\>";
                    echo '</div>';
            }

        echo '</div>';
           }
     
     ?>
     </div>
```

Comment: check your line of `img` tag

Comment: First of all, why you assign `$underfolder = $value` - output `echo $underfolder` but continue then to work with `$value` ? I would really recommend you to either just use only `$value` or if you do a reassign, then use `$underfolder` everywhere after the reassign. And btw your image tag line is wrong. May you wanna look at all your escapes and `"`

Comment: can you please try once by changing the second foreach loop $value to $v or any other name.

Comment: @Tristup I tried changing $value to $vales, the code still work as before, with the same problem of not closing the DIV

Comment: If you can see the solution you chosen is same which I have told you. Maxim just changed the $value in second loop and inside it. However, it great it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your quotes in img tag and `$value` you reassign `$value`. Set different name in second `foreach()`

```
<div class="folders">
    <?php
    global $current_user;
    $current_user        = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_nambre = $current_user->user_login;
    $sottocartelle       = glob( "wp-content/uploads/$current_user_nambre/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR );
    foreach ( $sottocartelle as $value ) {
        echo "<div class='products'>";
        $contenuto = scandir( $value );
        echo $value;
        foreach ( $contenuto as $value1 ) {
            echo '<div class="image;" style="display:inline-block;">';
            echo "<a href='/$value/$value1'>download</a>";
            echo "<img src='/$value/$value1' height='100' height='100' width='100'>";
            echo '</div>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

This code should work fine.